# Estimating Battery Life

Tags: power, batteries

I am working on a design that needs to operate outside on two AA batteries for at least a year.

I have optimized the design to reduce power and using a spreadsheet analysis I now have an average current consumption. I should be able to verify that is right by monitoring a prototype for a while.

I have the following pieces of information:

- Average current consumption in mA \$Cave\$
- Supply of Duracell AA batteries in mAh \$Bsupply\$
- Starting battery voltage \$Bmax\$
- Minimum battery voltage for DC-DC converter \$Bmin\$
- Non-linear discharge profile from Duracell website https://d2ei442zrkqy2u.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/MN1500_US_CT1.pdf
- Climate data

How can I take this to create a realistic estimate?

I think it is perhaps reasonable to use the average environmental temperature \$Tave\$.

Note - I chose Duracell simply as an exemplar of a quality battery. I wouldn't need/want to consider poorer-quality batteries.

Many thanks!

Update - average power consumption is 1.11mW.

Comment: what temperature range? <0'C?

Comment: mAH is not a measure of power, it is a measure of electrical charge/battery capacity.   For Pave I think you mean mW or equivalent power draw?   Same goes for Psupply — it should be in mAH but is not a measure of power, but battery charge/capacity.

Comment: Temp range is 0C to 22C, so very close to the range shown on the Duracell data.

Comment: What is the total energy usage of your circuit per year? If it is much much less than the energy capacity of the cells then you don't need to calculate anything else. Although that would be a boring answer.

Comment: Maybe you should start with communicating what is the power consumption of your device.

Comment: I've added the power consumption.

Comment: Chances are slim that a boost converter will work that long due to rising ESR of the battery and low DCR of the switched coil. So dynamic circuit impedance must be known.

Comment: 1.11mW sounds high. If your goal is roughly 10k hours, that would be 11 Wh of energy, or almost 4 Ah @ 3V -- a bit much for AA cells. You need to be about an order of magnitude lower than that. Typical alkaline AA capacity of 2500 mAh / 10k hours = 250 uA average consumption.

Comment: Dave - there are two parameters that can be configured at runtime in the software that can reduce the power further if needed. What I am stuck with is the non-linear nature of the discharge and temperature and how to model that. I was trying to keep my question generic rather than use specific values, but I was asked what it was. :)

Comment: You really don't need to worry about that level of detail; just get the total energy right.

Comment: @Andy, don't bother worrying about the nonlinearity. Temperature effects, etc, mean you'll only get an order-of-magnitude estimate anyway. Just do a rough calculation and then give yourself a good engineering margin.

Comment: I have alarm bells at mentioning of a DC-DC converter for something which needs run a looong time from batteries. What does your application (without converter!) need as voltage and what does it use as current?

Comment: Is the use of AA cells a requirement or just a nice-to-have feature?

Comment: 3.3V, 0.335mA average (varies from uA to 4mA). Two AA cells is a requirement I can't change.

Comment: You might be able to do it with lithium primary cells, going by the charts at [Energizer L91 data sheet](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/l91.pdf).

Comment: @Andrew - Thanks for the suggestion - I will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make a realistic ballpark estimate before going to intergraion of discharge curves and buck boost converter inefficiencies.

The estimate would be: at 3 V input supply and 1.11 mW, the device will take about 0.45mA average (assuming 80% efficiency of converter, if any). The Duracell discharge curve says about 650 service hours at 5 mA discharge rate. At 0.45 mA it will take about 11 times longer, or about 7200 hours. This is about 300 days of operation. Which is about 20% short of one year.

Conclusion: you can't guarantee this device to work for a year from 2xAA batteries. No amount of more accurate mathematical massaging of discharge curves would change this conclusion.

Comment: OK, so putting in my actual numbers. 3.3V, 1.11mA, 0.335mA, 94% converter efficiency, gives me  9114h = 379d

Comment: @Andy That's assuming something like a constant 20 degree C environment. Lower temperatures will reduce the energy that can be drawn from the cells.

Comment: @Andrew - yes, that is what I was originally worried about.

Comment: @Andy, 94% upconverter efficiency at 300 uA load is a bit optimistic, see TI Webench, 87-90% maybe. As of current state, this design has no margins on regular 2AA source. You might want to consider specifying lithium AA batteries instead, like http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/l91.pdf

Comment: @Ali Yes, but now I can play around with the firmware configuration to get the margin I need. :)

Comment: @Andy, actually you might have a little bit more margins, since your load looks like a pulsing load, 4 mA with 10% duty cycle. AFAIK,  batteries have better effective capacity on pulsed discharge. But this needs to be characterized on your own since manufacturer lists only continuous discharge.